# how does RandomizedLasso in sklearn use the variable n_jobs?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

When I have to parallelize an algorithm in python I usually use the multiprocessing map function.

In sklearn randomized Lasso it seems that they are using something of different [RandomizedLasso](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/randomized_l1.py)

I am not very expert of parallel computing in python and I hope that I can learn something new from this.

Can anyone explain me what are they using?
In their situation I would have used multiprocessing. Why did they choose something of different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n_jobs` is fed to [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/), which is used for all parallel processing in scikit-learn. As you can see on the joblib website, it's much easier to use than multiprocessing; it's also more feature-rich, as it can use either processes or threads (faster when executing C code) and has shared-memory support for NumPy arrays.